# Subclass of UITableViewCell dont show text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a strange problem with my subclass of an UITableViewCell. It contains an `UITextField` and an `UILabel`.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.textField = textField;
        self.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        [self addSubview:textField];
        [textField release];
        UILabel *captionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [captionLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        [captionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        self.captionLabel = captionLabel;
        [captionLabel release];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.captionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 80, 20);
    self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(150, 10, 200, 20);
}
```

Then I set the values like...
`textFilterCell.captionLabel.text = textFilter.caption;`

Strangely I can set all stuff on my textField that works... but when I set the Text on my Label nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `captionLabel` to the cell view:

```
[self addSubview:self.captionLabel];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to add it on superview.

```
[self addSubview:self.captionLabel];
```

Comment: cause of Asperger syndrome, people become over-focused or obsessed on a single object or topic, ignoring all others. just kidding...welcome bro...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set back groundColor for captionLabel for testing it

```
cell.captionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.contentView addSubview:self.captionLabel];
```